# org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.wms.wms.mapper.UserMapper.listAll

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mybatis-plus

When I run my project, and input `http://localhost:8090/list` ,I got a Whitelabel Error Page. Meanwhile, appeared the following error message in my backend console:

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.wms.wms.mapper.UserMapper.listAll
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MybatisMapperMethod.java:242) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperMethod.<init>(MybatisMapperMethod.java:54) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperProxy.lambda$cachedMapperMethod$0(MybatisMapperProxy.java:65) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperProxy.cachedMapperMethod(MybatisMapperProxy.java:65) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperProxy.invoke(MybatisMapperProxy.java:60) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.listAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.wms.wms.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.listAll(UserServiceImpl.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.wms.wms.service.impl.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7bd9df04.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at com.wms.wms.service.impl.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c935a041.listAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.wms.wms.controller.HelloController.list(HelloController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_371]
```

The configuration is as follows.

src>main>java>com.wms.wms>controller>**HelloController.java**:

```
package com.wms.wms.controller;

import com.wms.wms.entity.User;
import com.wms.wms.service.UserService;
import com.wms.wms.service.impl.UserServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello wms!";
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public List<User> list(){
       return userService.listAll();
    }
}
```

src>main>java>com.wms.wms>entity>**User.java**:

```
package com.wms.wms.entity;

import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.annotation.TableField;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String no;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private int age;
    private int sex;
    private String phone;
    private int roleId;
    private String isvalid;
}
```

src>main>java>com.wms.wms>mapper>**UserMapper.java:**

```
package com.wms.wms.mapper;

import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.mapper.BaseMapper;
import com.wms.wms.entity.User;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;

import java.util.List;

@Mapper
public interface UserMapper extends BaseMapper<User> {
    List<User> listAll();
}
```

src>main>java>com.wms.wms>service>**UserService.java**:

```
package com.wms.wms.service;

import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.service.IService;
import com.wms.wms.entity.User;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserService extends IService<User> {
    List<User> listAll();
}
```

src>main>java>com.wms.wms>service>Impl>**UserServiceImpl.java**:

```
package com.wms.wms.service.impl;

import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.service.impl.ServiceImpl;
import com.wms.wms.mapper.UserMapper;
import com.wms.wms.service.UserService;
import com.wms.wms.entity.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl<UserMapper,User> implements UserService {
    @Resource
    private UserMapper userMapper;
    @Override
    public List<User> listAll() {
        return userMapper.listAll();
    }
}
```

src>main>java>com.wms.wms>**WmsApplication.java**:

```
package com.wms.wms;

import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@MapperScan("com.wms.wms.mapper")
@SpringBootApplication
public class WmsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WmsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

src>main>resources>mapper>**UserMapper.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.wms.wms.mapper.UserMapper">
    <select id="listAll" resultType="com.wms.wms.entity.User">
        select * from user;
    </select>
</mapper>
```

src>main>resources>**application.yml**:

```
server:
  port: 8090

spring:
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wmsdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=GMT%2B8
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      username: root
      password: root
```

mysql table(have added data in the table):

```
create table user
(
    id int(4) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    no varchar(20) null,
    name varchar(20) not null,
    password varchar(20) not null,
    age int null,
    sex int null,
    phone varchar(20) null,
    role_id int null,
    isValid varchar(4) default'Y' null
);
```

To get the correct data in http://localhost:8090/list rather than whitelabel error page, how can I do? Anyone's help will be very appreciated, thanks!